# Get the names of all the files/folders in an array

Tags: gradle, groovy

Basically I have a folder in that I have 4 zip files. I want to get the names of these zip files in an array.

Requirement :
I have a folder AggregatedComponetLibraries: I have my lib zips inside it. a.zip,b.zip,c.zip,d.zip. I want to get the name of the zips insde an array componentNames in gradle that means my array should contain : a,b,c,d

Comment: Sure, the same way you'd do that in Java

Comment: Do you want only sub folders name or both subFiles/subFolders.. Please provide a structure actually what you want?

Comment: I used this     File directory = new File(outputDir)
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    fList.each{ file1 ->
        if(file1.isFile()){
            files.add(file1)
        }

        println(files)
    }

Comment: I get an error 'Could not find matching constructor'

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide additional information.

Comment: i made some corrections. Please see if there s any more clarification required

Comment: i made some corrections. Please see if there s any more clarification required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it with `FileTree` so:

```
def names = []
fileTree(dir: 'AggregatedComponetLibraries', include: '**/*.zip').visit {
    FileVisitDetails details ->
        names << details.file.name
}
task printNames << {
    println names
}
```

Here is the `names` array defined and then created a `FileTree` instance, for directory named "AggregatedComponetLibraries", this tree includes all the files with zip extention. After that, script traverses over the tree elements and add the element's names into the array.

Task `printNames` here is just to show the result.